# Querying partition sizes in CosmosDB

Tags: api, sdk, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is it possible to programmatically query the size of a given partition in CosmosDB (Core/SQL API), or ideally a list of all partitions in a container and their sizes?  I'm using the .NET SDK.

I'm considering a strategy of automatically archiving older data to archive partitions when the "main" partition approaches 20GB to avoid hitting the limit

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using Cosmos DB .Net SDK will give you that answer. You will need to use Azure Monitoring SDK to get this information. Essentially you will use the following Kusto query to get the information:

```
CDBPartitionKeyStatistics
// Get the latest storage size for each logical partition key value
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by AccountName, DatabaseName, CollectionName, _ResourceId, PartitionKey 
| extend utilizationOf20GBLogicalPartition = SizeKb / (20.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0) // Current storage / 20GB
| project TimeGenerated, AccountName, DatabaseName, CollectionName, _ResourceId, PartitionKey, SizeKb, utilizationOf20GBLogicalPartition
```

Above query is taken from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-alert-on-logical-partition-key-storage-size